# Azure Webbot would not connect to QnA maker knowledge base even after setting it correctly

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

This is my first attempt in creating any kind of chatbots. 
So created the necessary accounts and followed the process of creating a knowledge base and bot framework.

Inputted all 3 parameters  and saved correctly
QnAKnowledgebaseId 
QnAAuthKey
QnAEndpointHostName

Event restarted the bot. However, the bot would not connect to the knowledge base hence does not return answers to any of my queries.

Can someone please guide me how to connect the bot to knowledge base properly. Any steps missing

Looks for help and advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial I have used to create a QnA KB along with a Azure Web App Bot.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot#connect-your-qna-maker-knowledge-base-to-the-bot

What happens when you try the "Test in Web Chat" option within the Azure Portal.  Does it work for you?

Can you double check your applications settings on your Web App Bot?

QnAKnowledgebaseId = This should be just the GUID and not /knowledgebases/GUID/generateAnswer

QnAAuthKey = This should be just the AUTH_KEY and should not include the word EndpointKey AUTH_KEY

QnAEndpointHostName = Should be the QnA Maker URI such as: https://QNA_URI.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker

Thanks.
James